# CreateJS Sprite play() doesn't loop after gotoAndStop()?

Tags: sprite, createjs

I have an animation defined by "die:{frames:[65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70]}" which loops just fine when I alternate between play() and stop(). However, if I try to alternate between play() and gotoAndStop(#), where # is a frame number, play() doesn't loop. I have tried too many things to list them here. It seems I am misunderstanding something basic. Anyone know what?

Comment: By "doesn't loop" I don't mean it stops. It just keeps going and appears to loop through every frame in the spritesheet.

Comment: I am still interested in an answer :)